# Capacitor: Check if file exists

Tags: capacitor

What is the "correct" way of checking if file exists using Capacitor's native filesystem API?

The closest I could find is to use `stat()` method in a `try/catch` block; which does not feel right.

```js
try {
  const ret = await Filesystem.readFile({
    path: 'some-file.txt',
    directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data
  });
} catch (e) {
  // File not found, BUT can be something else!
  // So it is probably not the best way of going ...
}
```

Is there any better option? The functionality is so common that if feels like there must be something built in.

Comment: No: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/blob/d67d460127fb285810ad4aa7850381caea5e8499/electron/src/electron/filesystem.ts#L16, looks like a good PR XD, exists & existsync ^^

Answer (score 2):

To check if a file or a directory exists you can use Filesystem.stat it is clean and simple

```
/**
 * check if file or directory exists
 * @param getUriOptions options for
 * @returns boolean true if file exists
 */
async checkFileExists(getUriOptions: GetUriOptions): Promise<boolean> {
  try {
    await Filesystem.stat(getUriOptions);
    return true;
  } catch (checkDirException) {
    if (checkDirException.message === 'File does not exist') {
      return false;
    } else {
      throw checkDirException;
    }
  }
}

console.log('File exists: ', await this.checkFileExists({
          path: 'some-file.txt',
          directory: Directory.ExternalStorage
        }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes there is a way: You can first do a 'readdir' (read directory) at the root, then loop through the result looking for a match.  If no match is found, then you can have it return 'false'. Here's an example:

```
function verifyIfExists(ITEM, LIST) {
  let verification = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < LIST.length; i++) {
    if (LIST[i] === ITEM) {
      verification = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return verification;
}

async function readdir() {
  try {
    let ret = await Filesystem.readdir({
      path: '/',
      directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents
    });
    if (verifyIfExists('some-file.txt', ret.files)) {
      console.log("It exists!");
    }
    else {
      // Do something else
    }
  } 
  catch(e) {
    console.log('Unable to read dir: ' + e);
  }
}

readdir();
```

Comment: your uppercase parameter names hurt my eyes but your code is otherwise good